# Azure B2C - How do you test for authentication?

Tags: authentication, azure-ad-b2c

Since the B2C Sign In policy allows the user to select 'keep me logged in', when my **B2C** Web Application starts up, I need to know if the user is still authenticated so I know whether to display the 'Log In' or 'Log Out' menu items.

The **User.Identity.IsAuthenticated** always responds false when you first call it, but appears to work after the first time an '[Authenticate]' method is called.

Here's what my Startup code looks like:

```
/// <summary>
/// Configure the services that are available through Dependency Injection.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="services">A collection of services.</param>
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Configure DI to use authentication options, the Business to Consumer policies, and the API service options.
    services.Configure<ClientAuthenticationOptions>(this.configuration.GetSection("ClientAuthentication"));
    services.Configure<B2CPolicyOptions>(this.configuration.GetSection("B2CPolicies"));
    services.Configure<ServiceOptions>(this.configuration.GetSection("Service"));

    // These proxies are used to access the Web API.  This will eventually be replaced with a repository.
    services.AddTransient<ServiceProxy>();

    // Make MVC services availble for Dependency Injection.
    services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add(typeof(ReauthenticationRequiredFilter)));

    // Add Kendo UI service to the service container.
    services.AddKendo();

    // Configure additional classes to be instantiated through DI.
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    // A distributed memory cache is used to manage the cookies.
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

    // At this point we can build the service provider.
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    // The SSO requires a distributed cache to preserve the user's security token.
    this.distributedCache = serviceProvider.GetService<IDistributedCache>();
    services.AddSingleton(this.distributedCache);

    // This is where the Authentication system is configured.  We're using cookies to preserve the user's security tokens between calls to
    // the Web API, and we're using OpenID Connect protocol for authentication with the B2C service.
    this.clientAuthenticationOptions = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptions<ClientAuthenticationOptions>>().Value;
    this.b2CpolicyOptions = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptions<B2CPolicyOptions>>().Value;
    services.AddAuthentication(options => Startup.GetAuthenticationOptions(options))
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect(Constants.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationScheme, options => this.GetOpenIdConnectOptions(options));
}
```

And here's what I do when I log out:

```
/// <summary>
/// Remove the user's authorization.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The result of this action.</returns>
public async Task<IActionResult> SignOut()
{
    if (this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        await this.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        var callbackUrl = this.Url.Action("SignOutCallback", "Account", values: null, protocol: this.Request.Scheme);
        var policyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> { { Constants.B2CPolicy, this.User.FindFirst(Constants.TfpClaimType).Value } };
        await this.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(
            Constants.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationScheme,
            new AuthenticationProperties(policyDictionary) { RedirectUri = callbackUrl });

        // This process may take a few seconds, so this page provides feedback that we're trying to log them out.
        return this.View();
    }

    // If the user isn't authenticated the just redirect them to the home page.
    return this.RedirectToPage("/" + nameof(Index));
}

/// <summary>
/// Completes the sign-out action asynchronously.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The result of this action.</returns>
public IActionResult SignOutCallback()
{
    if (this.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // Redirect to home page if the user is authenticated.
        return this.RedirectToPage("/" + nameof(Index));
    }

    return this.View();
}
```

Comment: The typical approach is that if they don't have an active session in your app, they are logged out from your app's point of view. In that case you show Log In. Then if they were already logged in to B2C, they'll be immediately logged in.

Comment: Thank you.  You've described how it works, but you haven't described how my application knows which state -- Logged In or Logged Out -- they are in when the application starts.  It's critical to know this if you're going to give them the proper menu items.

Comment: Well, `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` should be `true` at the start if they are still logged in. Seems like your app does not accept the login cookie anymore?

Comment: Or your cookie authentication is not getting triggered. Could you show some code?

Comment: Added some code to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't test for this, i.e. "Have I been kept signed in". If the application doesn't have a cookie, because the user has begun a new session, then it should display "Log in". If Azure AD B2C does have a cookie, because the user kept themselves signed in from the previous session, then they shouldn't be prompted to enter their credentials.